# Help with gpgme_passphrase_cb_t

Tags: gnupg, gpgme

I'm working with GPGME...I need an example on use of `gpgme_passphrase_cb_t` and `gpgme_set_passphrase_cb` function because I don't understand how to create a `gpgme_passphrase_cb_t`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code from gpgme++ that wraps the callback-based interface into a C++ interface:

The interface:

```
class PassphraseProvider {
public:
  virtual ~PassphraseProvider() {}

  virtual char * getPassphrase( const char * useridHint,
                                const char * description,
                                bool previousWasBad,
                                bool & canceled ) = 0;
};
```

The function is supposed to display `description` as a prompt, and return the passphrase entered (the buffer must be `malloc()`ed). It may also set `canceled` to `true` to indicate that the user aborted. The parameters `useridHint` and `previousWasBad` are just additional information.

And this this the generic callback:

```
// Code taken from gpgme++, license: LGPLv2+
static
gpgme_error_t passphrase_callback( void * opaque, const char * uid_hint, const char * desc,
                                   int prev_was_bad, int fd ) {
  PassphraseProvider * provider = static_cast<PassphraseProvider*>( opaque );
  bool canceled = false;
  gpgme_error_t err = GPG_ERR_NO_ERROR;
  char * passphrase = provider ? provider->getPassphrase( uid_hint, desc, prev_was_bad, canceled ) : 0 ;
  if ( canceled )
    err = make_error( GPG_ERR_CANCELED );
  else
    if ( passphrase && *passphrase ) {
      size_t passphrase_length = std::strlen( passphrase );
      size_t written = 0;
      do {
#ifdef HAVE_GPGME_IO_READWRITE
        ssize_t now_written = gpgme_io_write( fd, passphrase + written, passphrase_length - written );
#else
        ssize_t now_written = write( fd, passphrase + written, passphrase_length - written );
#endif
        if ( now_written < 0 ) {
          err = make_err_from_syserror();
          break;
        }
        written += now_written;
      } while ( written < passphrase_length );
    }

  free( passphrase );
#ifdef HAVE_GPGME_IO_READWRITE
  gpgme_io_write( fd, "\n", 1 );
#else
  write( fd, "\n", 1 );
#endif
  return err;
}
```

Given an implementation `pp` of the `PassphraseProvider` interface, you'd tie everything together like this:

```
gpgme_set_passphrase_cb( ctx, &passphrase_callback, pp );
```